# В SSMS в login name (в заголовке таба и в строке состояния) после собственно логина в скобках какое-то число

Tags: sql-server

В SSMS в login name (в заголовке таба и в строке состояния) после собственно логина в скобках какое-то число.
Например: filename.sql - server.database (login (708))
Собственно, что это за число и можно ли от него избавиться? Плагином, настройками или еще как-то.

Comment: Это сессия, spid, зачем вам от него избавляться? Это нужная информация.

Comment: Это SPID, от него не нужно избавляться

Comment: Ну мне эта информация не нужна, за 8 лет ни разу не понадобилась, а из-за нее табов в строку вмещается меньше, поэтому и интересуюсь, как избавиться.

Comment: Никак не избавится. Если не нравится данная среда - можно поискать альтернативную среду.

Answer (score 3):

Нет, только SPID убрать нельзя, в SSMS для строки состояния и  названия вкладки (таба) можно включить/выключить отображение следующих элементов:

**Строка состояния:**

1. Время выполнения
2. Имя базы данных
3. Имя для входа
4. Имя сервера
5. Количество строк

**Название вкладки (таба):**

1. Имя файла
2. Имя базы данных
3. Имя для входа
4. Имя сервера

[image: Скриншот настроек SSMS]

Таким образом в строке состояния и заголовке владки (таба)  номер SPID можно отключить только вместе с именем учетной записи.